# Failed to create directory in Android (on MarshMallow and above) devices

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am trying to create a folder on my sdcard using the following code but it fails. This is my code written in `onCreate()`:

```
File test = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"my_directory");
if(!test.exists())
{
    try 
    {
        if (test.mkdir()) 
        {
            Log.d("xxx", "directory created");
        } 
        else 
        {
             Log.d("xxx", "directory creation failed");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else
{
    Log.d("xxx","directory already present");
}
```

When I run the above code does not give any exception it just prints the
`directory creation failed` log.

I have also given the following permission,

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

I am using Xiaomi Redmi note 3 and Android version is 6.0.1.

Comment: You have to request the permission at runtime if you're targeting SDK 23 and higher, are you doing that?

Comment: Are you using Marshmallow device to run this?

Comment: @KushPatel : Yes I am using marshmallow device .

Comment: @Egor: No I am requesting no permission on runtime, I guess that seems to be the problem ,I will try it out.Thanks.

Comment: `create a folder on my sdcard` AND `getExternalStorageDirectory()` do not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            //do your work
                        } else {
                            requestPermission();
                        }
                    }
           }


            protected boolean checkPermission() {
                int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            protected void requestPermission() {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
                    }
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 100:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //do your work
                    } else {
                        Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it just for API 21 (couse i wanted the same at my app, till now i do not know how to get on the sdcard)

you also need this in your manifest!!

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` declares the internal storage.
the exact path is: storage/emulated/0
you get it with:

`Log.i(TAG, "path is:" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());`

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() declares the internal storage`. No.Not internal.  You might look better at the function name as there it states very clearly  `ExternalStorage`.